# GCC inline ASM with variable

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, intel-syntax

I'm trying to use the following ASM inline code in my C++ source, given for Visual Studio :

```
__asm {
mov ecx,target
}
```

where target is a    void*    pointer. I don't know how to convert this into GCC-compatible code.
I know that GCC use synthax like :

```
asm (".intel_syntax noprefix");    
asm ("mov ecx,target");
```

but obviously there's a problem with the variable in this situation. So, anyone could explain me how to use a pointer with inline ASM using GCC for Windows ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to read this, here are some useful examples: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s7

Comment: this is useful: http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rmiyagi-inline-asm.txt

Comment: Also [this link](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html). GCC inline assembler is difficult! But for your simple case, I'm sure you will find a usable example among these three links.

Comment: 3 links and no one mentions the official gcc docs for asm (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)?  It's long and more detailed than a beginner might want, but it is the official source for gcc info, and pretty much everything you'd ever want to know is there.

Answer (score 1):

try this assembly this might help.... atleast it is working for me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *arg[])
{
  int retval;
  printf ( " retval = %d \n", retval );
  asm volatile(
           "movl %%ecx , %0\n\t"
           :"=r" (retval));    
  printf ( "retval = %d \n", retval );
  return 0; 
}
```

prints the following value for me ... I have tried it debugging the second value is same as the value present in ecx register.

> p $ecx

command in gdb

```
> retval = 0  
> retval = -72537468
```